# Is there a way to visualize, on the complex plane, complex numbers multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Easy question today (i suppose).

As title said, is it possible to visualize multiplications between two complex numbers over the complex plane?

Comment: Multiplication of absolute values and addition of arguments means scaling and rotation.

Comment: I would recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_0yfvm0UoU), by 3blue1brown. It begins with the complex plane around the 4-minute mark, although you should see from the beginning in order to understand what he's talking about. Although it's about something slightly different (the focus is understanding $e^{i\pi} = -1$), it shows a great way of thinking about multiplication and addition in the complex plane.

Comment: Check out the first chapter of [Needham's Visual Complex Analysis](http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m7034/book/VisualComplexAnalysis-Needham.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat, you have of course include the coordinate system in some way in the visualization.

Suppose you have two complex numbers $A$, $B$ and their product $C$ as points and the oringin O and unit $U$ (ie $1$). Then you can construct $C$ as constructing a triangle similar to $OUA$, but with the side $OB$ in place of $OU$. If that triangle is oriented the same way as $OUA$ it will be $OBC$.

Using complex arithmetics it's straight forward to see that this is correct.

Comment: What's really fun is the visualization for square roots of negative numbers over the complex plane.  It's a special case of the geometric mean, it just involves $OU$.  Hint: you can do it with compass and straight edge.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Use polar decomposition: then we are multiplying everything by $re^{i\theta}$. This can be carried out in two stages, (i) multiplication by $r$ then (ii) multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$.

In the first stage every complex number (regarding $x+iy$ it as a vector from origin joining $(x,y)$ ) geometrically  gets stretched by the factor of $r$ (or shrunk, if $r<1$).

In the second stage geometrically every number rotates around the origin by the angle $\theta$.

So a complex number multiplication involves these two geometrical transformations (in any order).